# HTML CSS Menu with Sub Menus

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a custom navigation bar with sub menus with very simple coding to keep it light but its not working properly. Please have a look at this code and fiddle link. Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/tjmkf9sb/

As you can see that I want to create a hoverable sub menu but the sub menus are not obeying `display: none` property right now. Please help.

CSS

```
.menu {
    border: 1px solid aliceblue;
    margin-top: 55px;
    margin-left: auto;
}
.menu li {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 15px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: #fff;
    background: red; /* For browsers that do not support gradients */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left top, #1fc8db, #2cb5e8); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(bottom right, #1fc8db, #2cb5e8); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom right, #1fc8db, #2cb5e8); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #1fc8db, #2cb5e8); /* Standard syntax */
    display: inline;
}
.menu li:hover {
    background: red; /* For browsers that do not support gradients */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left top, #26cfe3, #1aade4); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(bottom right, #26cfe3, #1aade4); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom right, #26cfe3, #1aade4); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #26cfe3, #1aade4); /* Standard syntax */
}
.menu a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}
.menu li ul {
    display: block;
}
.submenu ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="menu">
  <ul>
    <a href="dashboard.php"><li>Dashboard</li></a>
    <a href="dashboard.php">
      <li class="submenu">
        Licence Orders
        <ul class="dropdown">
          <li>Paid Orders</li>
          <li>Unpaid Orders</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </a>
    <a href="dashboard.php"><li>Dashboard</li></a>
    <a href="logout.php"><li>Logout</li></a>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Please help me. I have been stuck on this for quite some time now.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the HTML is invalid.

Comment: Now that's something weird I have come to know. How come this code can be INVALID??? Please explain....

Comment: Only `<li>` elements can be children of `<ul>` elements. What you have is invalid. Run it through a HTML validator and you'll see the errors.

Comment: @Rob Lol, that's no reason to close a question. In fact that is the exact reason the question was asked. They need help.

Comment: @brenjt It's not possible to fix a problem when the initial formula is not proper. There are validators one should know by heart to use when writing HTML and CSS. One needs unbroken, valid HTML first if they want their CSS fixed.

Comment: @brenjt Valid HTML is not about being perfect. Validating your markup is web development 101 and is the first step after writing HTML. Every rank amateur knows that.

Answer (score -1):

**Add:**

```
.menu li ul {
    display: none;
}

.menu li:hover ul {
    display: block;
}
```

```css
.menu {
 border: 1px solid aliceblue;
 margin-top: 55px;
 margin-left: auto;
}
.menu li {
 list-style: none;
 padding: 15px;
 border-radius: 5px;
 color: #fff;
 background: red; /* For browsers that do not support gradients */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left top, #1fc8db, #2cb5e8); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(bottom right, #1fc8db, #2cb5e8); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom right, #1fc8db, #2cb5e8); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #1fc8db, #2cb5e8); /* Standard syntax */
 display: inline;
}
.menu li:hover {
 background: red; /* For browsers that do not support gradients */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left top, #26cfe3, #1aade4); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(bottom right, #26cfe3, #1aade4); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom right, #26cfe3, #1aade4); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #26cfe3, #1aade4); /* Standard syntax */
}
.menu a:hover {
 text-decoration: none;
}
.menu li ul {
 display: none;
}

.menu li:hover ul {
  display: block;
}
.submenu ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="dashboard.php">Dashboard</a><li>
    <li class="submenu">
      <a href="dashboard.php">Licence Orders</a>
      <ul class="dropdown">
        <li>Paid Orders</li>
        <li>Unpaid Orders</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="dashboard.php">Dashboard</a></li>
    <li><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Style with your rules.

**Edit:** Only li can be descendent from ul

Comment: @Rob I would better like an explanation. Thank you!

Comment: But can you explain why was it invalid?

Comment: @ShubhamJha Only li can be descendent from ul

Comment: But what if I want the whole li to be clickable instead of only the text inside it?

Comment: @ShubhamJha li clickable is invalid. If you really need this you can use Javascript.

Comment: @ShubhamJha Example: invalid <a href="#><h2>text</h2></a> / valid <h2><a href="#">Text</a></h2>

Comment: still one problem.. the sub menu items are shown side by side like as if `display: inline` property is used.. its not being shown like one below the other like it must show when `display: block` property is used..

Comment: @RafaelGadottiBachovas Neither of those are invalid.